# Monthly statistics. ORA-01722: Invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

I use two choices to make monthly statistics. The first select selects the appropriate data, and then carefully counts the monthly statistics.

First select：

```
SELECT
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD') AS DA,
        ID,
        MAX (DAYRF) AS DAYRF
    FROM
        JC_T_QXJYJCSJ
    WHERE
        ID = 'G2001'
    GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD'),
        ID
    ORDER BY
        ID,
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD')
```

the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0K9A.png)
the final code:

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR (DA, 'RRRR-MM') AS DA1,
SUM (DAYRF)FROM(
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD') AS DA,
        ID,
        MAX (DAYRF) AS DAYRF
    FROM
        JC_T_QXJYJCSJ
    WHERE
        ID = 'G2001'
    GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD'),
        ID
    ORDER BY
        ID,
        TO_CHAR (ZDZDATETIME, 'RRRR-MM-DD')
) GROUP BY
TO_CHAR (DA, 'RRRR-MM');
```

Always prompt me for invalid numbers

I think the ID=‘G2001’ sentence has a problem, so I tried to change it to other ID='XXX' and it will run successfully. I don’t know if an error other than code has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question did not reveal much information about your issue.

I tried to convert your question into one problem statement and resolved the same using following query.

```
WITH DATAA(ID, DAYRF, DATE1) AS
(
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 9 , DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 15, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 12, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 5, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, DATE '2019-06-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 29 , DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 15, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 40, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 45, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 32, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 19, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2019-06-23' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    DATE1,
    SUM(MAX_DAYRF)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATE1,
            ID,
            MAX(DAYRF) AS MAX_DAYRF
        FROM
            DATAA
        GROUP BY
            DATE1,
            ID
    )
GROUP BY
    DATE1;
```

**Ouptut**

[image]

[Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e16f22b54b8fdf69326d5036c23a601e)

Cheers!!

Comment: I have changed my description, could you please help me again.

Comment: Check this: link [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9776a775218b930d0ff567ec8bb9d82)

Comment: Just use your data as an example:I now want to query the sum of DAYRF for ID=1 throughout the June.When there are multiple data in a day, take the one with the largest DAYRF, and the other ones are not.The result will be like this：（JUN-19      30 ）just when ID=1

Comment: Here you go: [DB FIddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f409fca30d6a7723b31493d87a48b1a1)

Comment: I succeeded according to your thinking, but there is a problem that seems to be not the code itself.I edit the question again